# Access control for resources behind server

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn, local-area-network, subnet

I would like to restrict VPN user access to a single LAN. I've been trying to wrap my head around the `client-config-dir` within the server.conf but can't get it working.

```
+---------+             +---------+
| client1 |             | client2 |
+---------+             +---------+
           \           /
            +---------+
            | server  | 10.10.1.23
            +---------+
                 |
            +---------+
            |   vpc   | 10.10.0.0/16
            +---------+
                 |
            +---------+
            |  local  | 10.10.0.112
            +---------+
```

```
+-------------------------------+
| VPC  |     subnet   | region  |
+------+------------+-----------+
| vpc0 | 10.10.0.0/16 | region0 |
+------+-------------+----------+
```

With my current openvpn setup I am able to connect to all instances behind the VPC. However I need client1 to only be able to access Machine 10.10.0.112 & client2 only access machine 10.10.0.222. I have been playing around with the `ccd` directive and iptables but can't wrap my head around it.

My Openvpn `server.conf`

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.10.0.2"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
dh none
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key 0
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_4nP1zpKP5eaV6jEz.crt
key server_4nP1zpKP5eaV6jEz.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
log-append /home/ubuntu/openvpn.log
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

client1.ovpn

```
client
proto udp
remote **.**.***.*** 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_4nP1zpKP5eaV6jEz name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
```

Route table for **server** `netstat -nr`

```
0.0.0.0         10.10.1.1       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
10.10.1.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

IP ROUTE `ip route`

```
default via 10.10.1.1 dev eth0 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.1 
10.10.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.1.140
```

CCD for **CLIENT**

Need help with the client-config-dir, only want client1 to be able to access10.10.0.112, as of right now can access all LAN machines behind VPN server.

IPTABLE FOR CLIENT

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 10.10.0.112 -j ACCEPT
```

If someone can point me to the right direction, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign fixed IPs to the clients. E.g. `ccd/client1` might contain:

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.112 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.10.0.112"
```

This way the client receives a fixed address (`10.8.0.112`) and a route for the host `10.10.0.112` only. The client can of course override the configuration sent by the server and add some of its own, e.g.:

```
pull-ignore "ifconfig"
# this will fail
ifconfig 10.8.0.222 255.255.255.0
# this will work
route 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0
```

The server will drop all packets coming from `client1`, which do not have an address of `10.8.0.112` so the `ifconfig` directive will not work, but this is not security feature, rather a technical limitation. The `route` directive on the other hand will work as requested.

Therefore you need to add firewall rules on the VPN server:

```
# Access to DNS server
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 53 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 10.10.0.2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 53 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 10.10.0.2 -j ACCEPT
# Access for client1
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.112 -d 10.10.0.112 -j ACCEPT
# Drop everything else
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 10.10.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

Comment: Dude you're legend.Thank you so much.I have one last problem, when the vpn connects the client can't use internet

Comment: The `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"` directive tells the client to route everything through the VPN connection. If you don't need it, remove the directive.

Comment: Appreciate your help honestly. Given me a better overall understanding.